# Routing in codeigniter the right way

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I'm developing my home page, this has a login button on the top right corner. I'd like to display a login page when the "login" text like so:

```
<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link header-text" href="<?php echo 
site_url('Login/login') ?>">Login</a>
</li>
```

So the controller is called "Login" and the view is "login".

My routing rules in the routes.php file are the following

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

My base url is: http://localhost:8080/
My site url is: http://localhost:8080/index.php

And my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

The way this is currently setted up is not working for routing, i get a 404 not found message if i click the login and i get redirected to this url: 
    http://localhost:8080/index.php/Login/login.html
Can you please help me troubleshooting this problem? thanks!

EDIT: 
Here's the Login controller code:

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page_name = 'login')
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page_name.'.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page_name); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page_name, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
```

}

Comment: I carefully read the codeigniter tutorial at this link:
    https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html
My actual configuration is the same one of the tutorial. So i tried loading this URL: 
    http://localhost:8080/app/index.php/login
And the login page is actually loaded but with a problem: without css... trying to troubleshoot this right now

Comment: P.s. the header and footer files are loaded because i don't get any loading error... The css for the homepage is loaded. The header and footer are always the same and are located into views/templates

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` and see what happens. It is grabbing **every** request and redirecting it to 'pages/view'.

I worry you misunderstand how CodeIgniter (CI) uses URLs. You said,

> So the controller is called "Login" and the view is "login".

Which leads me to believe that URLs represent

```
example.com/class/view
```

when they actually represent this

```
example.com/class/function/id/
```

where 'id' is one or more values to be passed to the function.

Perhaps your comment was a misstatement, but if not I recommend rereading the [CodeIgniter URLs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) section of the docs. You might also find the section [URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) valuable as it clearly defines when you might want to use /config/Routes.php

The login URL is quite strange too. I'm curious to see what the controller code looks like.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I expressed myself poorly... I explain. The controller name is Login.php and the class name is Login. If i delete 
    $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
It just can't find the right path since i nested inside the view folder another one which name is "pages"... Maybe, as you asked, if I show you my controller code it's easier so I add it right now in the description!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it! 
Basically I had a wrong idea on the standard routing rules I created following the tutorial. To solve the problem I had to: 
1) change my base_url to: http://localhost:8080/app. I added the /app
2) The right way to route to a view in this case is: http://localhost:8080/app/index.php/name_of_the_class; 
3) to load the css for every page I had to use the base_url syntax in the link tag like so: 
    " type="text/css" media="all">

If you have any suggestion, best practice or something I can do better I'm here!